# django url tag problem

Tags: django

I have problem with url tag. I want to redirect to a function that is in for eg
project_name.forum.views.function. Here is how i try to create url

```
{% url forum.views.function %}
```

it gives me this error:

```
Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried forum in module project_name.forum.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'forum'
```

I added this url in urls.py(I can access it directly) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like an incorrectly set up URL conf. You get that error when you specify a view that doesn't exist.

The url tag failing gives you a `failure to reverse url with params...` message.

What does your URL conf look like? Does `project_name.forum.views.forum` exist?

I mean, I find it odd you can visit the page at all, but that's the first place I'd look.

Comment: Here is my part of mu urls.py urlpatterns +=patterns('project_name.forum.views',
    (r'^function$','function'),
).project_name.forum.views.forum does not exist but I don't want url to point on it. I want to do link to project_name.forum.views.function which exist. Where from project_name.forum.views.forum came? In url is good views function so why he is trying to call project_name.forum.views.forum?

Comment: But does `project_name.forum.views.forum` actually exist? (ie can you do `from project_name.forum.views import forum`) Do you have a url line pointing to it?

Comment: it does't exist but i don't want to point it. I want to do link to project_name.forum.views.function and this exist and can be accessed directly from browser just url tag don't want to work with it don't know why

Comment: I understand that you don't want to point to it, but django is complaining about it, so you must be pointing to it somewhere (this non existent function `forum`): would you mind posting your whole url conf somewhere? Url conf issues are the hardest to debug in django, imo. The only wild goose chases I've been on are with urls.

Comment: Sorry it is not in english but here is code of urls.py views and template. I want to use wyloguj from przypomnienia.views in my template. http://www.wklejto.pl/89929

Comment: Hah, I love it! Ok, so comment out `(r'^przypomnienia$','przypomnienia'), <--` does this view exist?

Comment: OFC  it does not exist.I forgot to remove it. So stupid mistake. I removed it now and everythink work just perfectly. But I still don't understand why he called this function not the one I called? He was processing urls.py and stop on this line and don't parse the rest? I just try to understand it for future to avoid dummies questions

Comment: Hey Artur, any time you call the `reverse()` function which is what the `{% url %}` tag is doing, it goes through all of your views to try to figure out what the URL should be. There's a fat warning here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse  99% of the time, the error message is very helpful (as it was in your case). 1% of the time, it leads you to wild goose chases and always involves the url module.

Comment: Thanks for help I will remember about in next time

Answer (score 2):

The url tag is used to reference named urls. E.g.

```
url(r'^$', 
    login_required(views.user_babies),
    name='babystats_user_babies'),
```

Then you use {% url babystats_user_babies %} (the url pattern name, not the view name)

Comment: No, it accepts view names as well. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: I just don't know how to write "path.to.some_view". I have exactly the same problem with function redirect from shortcuts it gave to me exactly the same error

Comment: Your syntax is exactly right. `{% url forum.views.function %}`, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: But still using named URLs should be preferred over view function names. +1 for that

Comment: @Yuji Thanks for the comment, I wasn't aware of using view names directly in url. Although I find named URLs a more robust approach

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error before with django url reversing stemming from the urlconf being set up with a root like projectname.app.views.view instead of app.views.view, so it chokes on the reverse without the name of the project.

Another common issue would be that the url takes an extra parameter that can be blank, and it needs you to pass an empty string or whatnot.

Comment: I remove project_name from urls.py and still the same. The function only take one parameter request and in urls.py i don't capture any parameters so i think here is fine